# Find age between 15 to 25 years from a given column of date of birth?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL which function should I use to find age between 15 to 25 years from a given column of date of birth? Also date of birth column is given in `varchar()` and we have to write syntax in select statement only.

Comment: Looks like homework? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You shouldn't be stored a date in a `varchar` column either.